# Problems to make a class active

Tags: jquery, button

I am working in a website using php, css and jquery to show information based in a day menu.

I built a menu using **li** to represent the days from Monday through Friday.

I have tried using the following Jquery code to add a class, without any luck, to make my buttons active when ever I click over.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dias li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("actidia");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("actidia");
    return false;

  });
});
```

```css
.dias {
  list-style: none;
  width: 440px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.dias>li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 1px 12px 1px 12px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #F90;
  background-color: #F90;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.dias>li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: 1px solid #F60;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F60;
}

.dias>li a {
  color: #111;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.dias>li a:hover {
  color: #444;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dias .actidia {
  color: #555;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: rgba(255, 204, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dias">
  <li><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $lunes ?>">Lunes</a></li>
  <li><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $martes ?>">Martes</a></li>
  <li><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $miercoles ?>">Miercoles</a></li>
  <li><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $jueves ?>">Jueves</a></li>
  <li><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $viernes ?>">Viernes</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that I have to use **return false** to add a class and make my buttons active on click but whenever I use it my links don't work. If I take out **return false** my links work but the class is not applied. My buttons just flash.

I have spent many hours searching and trying to find a solution without any luck.

I will appreciate any help about this matter.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click a link? Isn't it supposed to take you somewhere?

Comment: It will go to the same page but it will filter by the day value I am sending. For example: menudia_user.php?day=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on linkpage will get refreshed. So it wont apply your jquery logic. You can do that with php logic.

You need another variable to store `$_GET` param. So declare below variable in your php code:

```
$dia = isset($_GET['dia']) ?$_GET['dia']:'';
```

To apply active class check the `$dia` with your `href` variable. If both are equal apply active class. Use below code & do it for other li

```
<li class="<?php echo $dia==$lunes?'actidia':''; ?>"><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $lunes; ?>">Lunes</a></li>
```

Comment: In effect is as you say it, the problem is that the page refreshes and the logic of jquery is lost. I had to use PHP to assign the class I need. I could not use the code you wrote to me but adapting the code to your answer worked for me.

Thank you very much. 

This is the code I used: 

<li class="<?php if ($vardia==$lun){echo 'actidia';} ?>"><a href="menudia_user.php?dia=<?php echo $lunes; ?>">Lunes</a></li>